# Test dynamic url in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have written a protractor test code that will pull the url of a blog. Each time a new blog post, the last url will be updated and will be shown on the website. I want to check whether the url is returning 404 or 200. if 404 comes, the test will be failed. Below is my code

```
describe('Writing to wiki how', function() {
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.sleep(1000);
it('test commmunity', function () {
    browser.get('https://www.debtconsolidationcare.com/');
    browser.sleep(5000);

    var knowhowimg = element(by.id('knowhowimg')).getAttribute("src").then(function (value) {
        console.log(value); //want to test if this returns 200
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    var knowhowimghref = element(by.id('knowhowimghref')).getAttribute("href").then(function (value) {
        console.log(value); //want to test if this returns 200
        browser.sleep(5000);


    });

    var knowhowheadhref = element(by.id('knowhowheadhref')).getAttribute("href").then(function (value) {
        console.log(value); //want to test if this returns 200

        browser.sleep(5000);
```

Those 3 console.log returns proper URL. I want to test those 3 urls that comes in console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Request](https://github.com/request/request) package is what you are looking for.
Example Usage:

```
var request = require('request');
describe('Writing to wiki how', function() {
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.sleep(1000);
it('Tests Community', function() {
   element(by.id('knowhowimg')).getAttribute("src").then(function (value) {
      request(value,function(error, response, body){
          console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
          console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
          expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
      });
   });
});
```

Without using the Request package (will likely take longer due to having to fully load the page)

```
describe('Writing to wiki how', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.sleep(1000);
    it('Tests Community', function() {
       element(by.id('knowhowimg')).getAttribute("src").then(function (value) {
          browser.get(value);
          expect(element(by.css('div.ElementOnNewPage')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy(); //define an element that exists ONLY on the new page here
       });
    });
```

The main difference is that you are checking for an element that is on the next page to appear, thus proving that the page loaded.

Comment: What will I do with that "Request" package? I have got ur code. But can't understan the Request Package link that u have shared above

Comment: @souvik I added a case for use without the Request function. Request is an NPM package, and I would advise using it, but both ways should work

Comment: @souvik [Here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/610) is a useful link for about testing URL with protractor that might help as well

Comment: Thank You for ur help. Have installed request package & ran the test. It really works. :) @ben